# Analisar se o número é par ou impar, e qual dos números é maior

Tags: c, c++, algoritmo

[image: O problema é esse.]

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");

int num1,num2;

printf("\nInforme os números: ");
scanf ("%i""%i",&num1,&num2);

if (num1 % 2 == 0){
    printf ("\nO número %i é par e",num1);
}else {
    printf("\nO número %i é impar e",num1);
}
if (num1>num2){
    printf (" é o número é o maior");
}else {
    printf(" é o número é o menor");
}



if (num2 % 2 == 0){
    printf ("\nO número %i é par e",num2);
}else {
    printf("\nO número %i é impar e"),num2;
}
if (num2>num1){
    printf (" é o número é o maior");
}else {
    printf(" é o número é o menor");
}
```

Quando coloco 2 e 3 da um erro no 3 e ele mostra vários números aleatórios mas o resultado está correto, já quando coloco o 4 e 6 ele diz que o 4 é par, poderia me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Olá, Luan. Evite de marcar com a tag C++ problemas em C. São duas linguagens muito diferentes. Evite também de usar imagens para descrever seu problema. O uso de imagens dificulta a busca e impossibilita a leitura por usuários de leitores de tela. Faça o nosso [tour] para familiarizar-se melhor com o site, caso não tenha feito.

Comment: Obrigado por seus conhecimentos mestre, o jovem padawan aqui os recebeu e ira praticá-los !

Answer (score 5):

Na instrução onde você exibe a variável `num2` quando é impar havia um erro na chamada da função `print()`, veja onde eu mudei:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    int num1,num2;

    printf("\nInforme os números: ");
    scanf ("%i""%i",&num1,&num2);

    if (num1 % 2 == 0){
        printf ("\nO número %i é par e",num1);
    }else {
        printf("\nO número %i é impar e",num1);
    }
    if (num1>num2){
        printf (" é o número é o maior");
    }else {
        printf(" é o número é o menor");
    }



    if (num2 % 2 == 0){
        printf("\nO número %i é par e",num2);
    }else {
        printf("\nO número %i é impar e",num2); //<----- mudei qui
    }
    if (num2>num1){
        printf (" é o número é o maior");
    }else {
        printf(" é o número é o menor");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Da forma anterior estava trazendo lixo, so foi preciso rescrever esta rotina para:

```
printf("\nO número %i é impar e",num2);
```

Assim é possível verificar o resultado da validação.

Comment: Deus do céu, estou muito desatento, vlw haha

Answer (score 2):

A forma mais simples de fazer, e sem erro de sintaxe já respondido em outra resposta:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num1, num2;
    printf("\nInforme os números: ");
    scanf("%d""%d", &num1, &num2);
    printf("\nO número %d é %s e é o número é o %s", num1, (num1 % 2 == 0 ? "par" : "impar"), (num1 > num2 ? "maior" : "menor"));
    printf("\nO número %d é %s e é o número é o %s", num2, (num2 % 2 == 0 ? "par" : "impar"), (num2 > num1 ? "maior" : "menor"));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/JT2tTa). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/tjbnchikoq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/EvenOdd3.c).

Answer (score 0):

É possível simplificar bastante o seu código, veja só:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define eh_par( n )      ( ( n % 2 ) ? 0 : 1 )
#define comparar( a, b ) ( ( a == b ) ? 0 : ( ( a > b ) ? 1 : -1 ) )

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    printf("a: ");
    scanf( "%d", &a );

    printf("b: ");
    scanf( "%d", &b );

    switch( comparar( a, b ) )
    {
        case -1: printf( "%d eh menor que %d\n", a, b ); break;
        case  0: printf( "%d eh igual a %d\n", a, b ); break;
        case  1: printf( "%d eh maior que %d\n", a, b ); break;
    }

    printf("%d eh um numero %s\n", a, eh_par(a)?"PAR":"IMPAR" );
    printf("%d eh um numero %s\n", b, eh_par(b)?"PAR":"IMPAR" );

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```

Saída:

```
$ ./teste
a: 5
b: 8
5 eh menor que 8
5 eh um numero IMPAR
8 eh um numero PAR

$ ./teste
a: 9
b: 4
9 eh maior que 4
9 eh um numero IMPAR
4 eh um numero PAR

$ ./teste
a: 5
b: 5
5 eh igual a 5
5 eh um numero IMPAR
5 eh um numero IMPAR
```

Espero que ajude!

Comment: E se eu disser q tem gente que gastou 6 ou mais " if " ? kkkkkk

Comment: Vlw, vou estudar case / switch